# Using sub queries

Tags: java, database, subquery, derby

I am trying to access a data in a table using a sub query. 
The table 1 contains a foreign key to table 2 , which means i can use that key to access the data in table 2.
My problem is  after i return the array list from the below shown method , the arraylist is null.

This is what i have done:

```
     LogEntry logBookDates;
    List<LogEntry> bookList =new ArrayList();
 try{
 PreparedStatement getSummaryStmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM LOGENTRYTABLE WHERE DIARYCODE =(SELECT Diarycode FROM LOGBOOKTABLE WHERE STUDENTUSERNAME=? OR SUPERVISORUSERNAME=? AND PROJECT_APPROVE_STATUS=?)");

//the above statment is the sub query which i have created, i get the diary code from   log book table and then access the log entry table.



  getSummaryStmt.setString(1,userName);
  getSummaryStmt.setString(2,userName);
  getSummaryStmt.setString(3,"Accepted");
  ResultSet rs=getSummaryStmt.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next())
 {
     logBookDates=new LogEntry(rs.getString("STUDENTUSERNAME"),rs.getString("SupervisorUsername"),rs.getString("projecttitle"),rs.getString("projectDescription"),rs.getDate("startDate"),rs.getDate("enddate"),rs.getString("project_approve_status"),rs.getString("diarycode"),rs.getString("projectcode"),rs.getInt("Index"),rs.getString("log_Entry"),rs.getDate("logentry_date"),rs.getString("supervisor_comment"),rs.getString("project_progress"));
     bookList.add(logBookDates);
 }

 }catch(Exception e){}
 return bookList;
 }
```

I have not used sub queries before and this is the first time am using them.
What seems to be the problem here ?

Thank you for your time.

Edit : Sample data of logbook table
[image]

Sample Data of logentry table 
[image]

Expected output:

I don't have a screen shot of that but what i need is just to iterate through the arraylist which will be returned from the above method.

Comment: can you post the table with some sample data and provide expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I get a null'? Is it that you are encountering a null value for one of the columns from the LogBookEntry table? When a query does not return any result, the result set 'rs' is never null - it is empty - which means rs.next() will return false.

Comment: by using `SELECT Diarycode FROM LOGBOOKTABLE WHERE STUDENTUSERNAME=? OR SUPERVISORUSERNAME=? AND PROJECT_APPROVE_STATUS=?)`, are you able to get the `Diarycode`?

Comment: I have provided with sample data and output, 

What i mean by " I get a null means" after i returned the arraylist (Which i am doing inside this method), and when i checked whether the returned arraylist is empty using the empty method , it returns true which means , it is null.

Comment: @ling.s, yes i tried without using subquery and just passing the diary code, i am able to retrieve the data.

Comment: @Shehan.W try this `SELECT DIARYCODE FROM LOGBOOKTABLE WHERE (STUDENTUSERNAME=? OR SUPERVISORUSERNAME=?) AND PROJECT_APPROVE_STATUS=?)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem, the `LOGENTRYTABLE` table doesn't contain a column with `STUDENTUSERNAME, SupervisorUsername, projecttitle, projectDescription, startDate,` etc...

```
 rs.getString("STUDENTUSERNAME"), rs.getString("SupervisorUsername"), etc...
```

probably, you need JOIN query

```
"SELECT * FROM LOGENTRYTABLE LT 
INNER JOIN LOGBOOKTABLE LB ON LT.DIARYCODE=LB.DIARYCODE
WHERE LT.DIARYCODE =
      (SELECT DIARYCODE FROM LOGBOOKTABLE
      WHERE (STUDENTUSERNAME=? OR SUPERVISORUSERNAME=?)
      AND PROJECT_APPROVE_STATUS=?)"
```